# Set/Unset a debug flag during grunt/requirejs build

Tags: javascript, debugging, build, requirejs, gruntjs

I am beginning with both [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs) and [gruntjs](/questions/tagged/gruntjs). I have a debug flag in the app like:

```
var debugEnabled = true;
```

Is there some way this can be set to `false`, automatically from within the `requirejs` optimization being run from within a `grunt` build?

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I have only one default task that runs the `requirejs` optimizer. The variable `debugEnabled` is within one of the modules within my app itself, say `AppLogger`, which is a dependency to `main`.

Is there some way the `requirejs` build can set this variable to `false`, so that the minified version of `AppLogger` would stop doing `console.log` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have two tasks:

- development
- production

`development` does all the stuff you need in development, like jshint, coffeescript compilation, ...
`production` does requirejs optimization, css minification, ...

Then you could register a `build` task which checks your debug flag:

```
    grunt.registerTask('build', 'run build', function () {
        var task = debugEnabled ? 'development' : 'production';

        // run the targetted task
        grunt.task.run(task);
    });
```

On the commandline, `grunt build` will execute it.

Alternatively, you could use the [option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) parameter in grunt:

```
    grunt.registerTask('build', 'run build', function () {
        // start development build by default
        var target = grunt.option('target') || 'development';

        // run the targetted task
        grunt.task.run(target);
    });
```

On the commandline, `grunt build --target=production` will execute it.

**Edit:**

Misunderstood the question a bit. The only way I see is to separate your debug flag in a separate module:

**path/to/debug.js**

```
define(function() {
   return true;
});
```

Then you create a production version (near your grunt tasks):

**path/to/grunt/tasks/debug.js**

```
define(function() {
   return false;
});
```

And in your `requirejs` task, you specify that version:

```
requirejs: {
   options: {
      paths: {
         debug: 'path/to/grunt/tasks/debug.js'
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I was looking for is slightly different and I have tried to clarify it with an update to the question.

Comment: This definitely would work, but figured out another option of build `pragmas` from the [r.js example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js). This apparently is what `jquery.mobile` [also uses](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.events.js). I have accepted your answer, but will add another of my own with what is working for me. Thank you!

Comment: And congrats on reaching 5 grand reputations! :-)

Answer (score 15):

[@asgoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916258/asgoth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15195973/218882) definitely would work, but figured out couple of other options as well to 'inject' (or remove rather) code during the build process.

As documented in the [example build.js file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/98ead89afaa601a4c4c7e37e967471703f89afea/build/example.build.js), we could use the build `pragmas` to include/exclude code snippets during the build process.

```
//Specify build pragmas. If the source files contain comments like so:
//>>excludeStart("fooExclude", pragmas.fooExclude);
//>>excludeEnd("fooExclude");
//Then the comments that start with //>> are the build pragmas.
//excludeStart/excludeEnd and includeStart/includeEnd work, and the
//the pragmas value to the includeStart or excludeStart lines
//is evaluated to see if the code between the Start and End pragma
//lines should be included or excluded. If you have a choice to use
//"has" code or pragmas, use "has" code instead. Pragmas are harder
//to read, but they can be a bit more flexible on code removal vs.
//has-based code, which must follow JavaScript language rules.
//Pragmas also remove code in non-minified source, where has branch
//trimming is only done if the code is minified via UglifyJS or
//Closure Compiler.
pragmas: {
    fooExclude: true
},

//Same as "pragmas", but only applied once during the file save phase
//of an optimization. "pragmas" are applied both during the dependency
//mapping and file saving phases on an optimization. Some pragmas
//should not be processed during the dependency mapping phase of an
//operation, such as the pragma in the CoffeeScript loader plugin,
//which wants the CoffeeScript compiler during the dependency mapping
//phase, but once files are saved as plain JavaScript, the CoffeeScript
//compiler is no longer needed. In that case, pragmasOnSave would be used
//to exclude the compiler code during the save phase.
pragmasOnSave: {
    //Just an example
    excludeCoffeeScript: true
},
```

I could see this in action on the `jquery.mobile` [code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/e802d5ad665480d91bdd67e22a2134609fb02d6a/js/events/navigate.js), which probably is a good place for learning `AMD` and `requirejs` from.

Here is what worked for me:

**AppLogger.js:**

```
/* global console: false */
define(function () {

  var debugEnabled = false;
//>>excludeStart('appBuildExclude', pragmas.appBuildExclude);
  debugEnabled = true;
//>>excludeEnd('appBuildExclude');
  return {
    log:function (message) {
      if (debugEnabled && console) {
        console.log('APP DEBUG: ' + message);
      }
    }
  };

});
```

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
requirejs:{
  compile:{
    options:{
      baseUrl:"js/",
      mainConfigFile:"js/main.js",
      name:'main',
      out:'js/main.min.js',
      pragmas:{ appBuildExclude:true }
    }
  }
}
```

With this configuration for the `requirejs` in my `Gruntfile`, the section within the pragmas of `excludeStart` and `excludeEnd` were stripped off from the compiled/built file.

I am still learning `requirejs`, so no claims that this is the best practice for this sort of thing, but this surely worked for me.

Comment: ain't it will be better (from optimization point of view) to wrap any log message in such comments, not the flag?